# DNS permissions for Availability Groups

Tags: availability-groups, dns

can anyone tell me the correct permissions for the Listener and Cluster records in DNS?

At the moment I have a single subnet AG where the Listener VNN owns the cluster DNS entry and vice versa, so the cluster CNO owns the Listener DNS entry.

I'm certain that the CNO should own its own DNS entry but I'm less certain about Listener DNS entry.

I keep reading this stackexchange ([https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301323/sql-server-2019-always-on-ensure-that-cluster-name-object-cno-is-granted-per#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20ensure%20both%20Cluster%20%26%20Listener,the%20cluster%20name%22%20Check%20%22Full%22%20under%20permission%20%22SQDB01%24%22](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301323/sql-server-2019-always-on-ensure-that-cluster-name-object-cno-is-granted-per#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20ensure%20both%20Cluster%20%26%20Listener,the%20cluster%20name%22%20Check%20%22Full%22%20under%20permission%20%22SQDB01%24%22))

But it makes no mention of the Listener DNS entry.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Alex

I can;t find a definitive (or any) guide to this